# Table with lists

Tags: tables, lists

[image]

How would I make a table such as the one above?

Comment: Showing a MWE could help add details to the proposed problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't call this a table but two boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
    function\_1 (a,b,c):\\
    \quad answer\_1 = a + b + c\\[\baselineskip]
    Where
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item a = param\_1
    \item b = param\_2
    \item c = param\_3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}%
}\kern-\fboxrule
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
    function\_2 (d,e,f):\\
    \quad answer\_2 = d + e + f\\[\baselineskip]
    Where
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item d = param\_1
    \item e = param\_2
    \item f = param\_3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

However, if you insist in using a table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*2{p{.45\textwidth}|}}
  \hline
  function\_1 (a,b,c): & function\_2 (d,e,f) \\
  \quad answer\_1 = a + b + c  & \quad answer\_2 = d + e + f \\[\baselineskip]
  Where
  \begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item a = param\_1
  \item b = param\_2
  \item c = param\_3
  \end{itemize}
  &
    Where
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item d = param\_1
    \item e = param\_2
    \item f = param\_3
    \end{itemize}
  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note: Maybe using math mode for the variables and the sum and `\text{…}` for `function`, `answer` and `param` would be better. But because, I don't know much about the semantic of the text and you've not shown a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), I've decided to reduce the answer to making the boxes resp. table instead of how to make the content as nice as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I would use `tabularx` package. By it is simpler to determine column width. Nice answer, +1.